# ANGULAR : how to get a video from the backend sending jwt token in headers

Tags: angular, security, video

hope you all doing well, 
i'm stacking in a real problem with Angular

the backend send me a object contains an Arrays of url for attachements (images or videos):

```
attachments:[{
    id: 4
    title: "d439e68f-ece6-4d80-a0b7-111fb337a8e6.jpeg"
    content: null
    file: "http://api-coldplace-dev.piman-analytics.fr/api/tutorial/4/attachments/4"
    type: "image"
    mime: "image/jpeg"
    duration: 0
    order: 0
    cover: 0
    external_link: 0
    },{
    id: 5
    title: "file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"
    content: null
    file: "http://api-coldplace-dev.piman-analytics.fr/api/tutorial/4/attachments/5"
    type: "video"
    mime: "video/mp4"
    duration: 31
    order: 1
    cover: 0
    external_link: 0
}]
```

to get that attachement, you have to do it with another http request GET to url (attachement.file ) sending jwt token in headers of that request (secure attachement).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEv2H.png)

[example of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gym6m.jpg)

i do this with secure pipe

HTML :

```
 <img *ngIf="file?.type?.toString()?.includes('image')"
                       [src]="file?.source | secure | async "
                       height="70px"
                       width="70px"/>
 <video *ngIf="file?.type?.toString()?.includes('video')"
                         height="70px"
                         width="70px"
                         [src]="file?.source | secure | async"
                         (loadedmetadata)="getDuration($event, i)">
```

PIPE :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'secure'
})
export class SecurePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(url): Observable<SafeUrl> {
    return this.http
      .get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
      .map(val => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val)));
  }

}
```

My problem is all of this works just for les attachements of type images, when it's a video, the request always get failed

example : 
[video request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEy9W.png)

[failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en3In.png)

i don't know if the type video, i have to do with another way or something like that, but i'm sure that the  problem is not from the backend, cause i tested in postman and i'm getting always the video

any help , please

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. But in some cases `blob.data` gives you the actual stream. Give this a try.

```
URL.createObjectURL(val.data) // assign val:any if neccessary
```

Give this a try for video.
If this works you'll have to put conditional logic in your pipe.

Comment: hi, no it does not enter the map, i add console.log(val), but im getting unknowerror http before enter the map